# AFJSONRequestOperation : crash stacktrace

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking, crash-reports, afjsonrequestoperation

I am trying to fix one crash in my app, but I have to be honest I was not able to figure this one out so far.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x378f90fc objc_retain + 12
1   myApp 0x00254ce3 __74+[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:]_block_invoke (AFJSONRequestOperation.m:54)
2   libdispatch.dylib 0x37de10c3 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
3   libdispatch.dylib 0x37de10af _dispatch_client_callout + 23
4   libdispatch.dylib 0x37de39a9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 269
5   CoreFoundation 0x2d56a5b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
6   CoreFoundation 0x2d568e7d __CFRunLoopRun + 1309
7   CoreFoundation 0x2d4d3471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
8   CoreFoundation 0x2d4d3253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
9   GraphicsServices 0x3220d2eb GSEventRunModal + 139
10  UIKit 0x2fd88845 UIApplicationMain + 1137
11  myApp 0x0012dc2b main (main.m:14)
12  libdyld.dylib 0x37df5ab7 start + 3
```

This crash report gives me no hints, I mean AFJSONRequestOperation.m:54 just call the completion block if present

```
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (success) {
        success(operation.request, operation.response, responseObject); // line 54
    }
  ...]
```

So I'm wondering if someone could help me, not to fix this but to give me some hints in finding the right direction to understand it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the crash report gives you more hints than you told us. Where does it say that it crashes in the main thread? Did you place a breakpoint at line 54 and also *in* your completion block?

Comment: If I was able to reproduce it, for sure I did not write on SO. so the breakpoints are there but the app has never stopped there. Regarding the main thread, Where did I say that it crashed on the main thread?

Comment: "Where did I say that it crashed on the main thread". here:  "_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF"  ;)   And, it's the main thread in your stack trace. If this is not the thread where you got an exception like EXC_BAD_ACCESS, please show the stack trace of *that* thread instead.

Comment: Ok, but I don't get the your point.. How the fact that the block is executed on the main thread, whether it is, could help me in figure this out?

Comment: I (we) can't unless you provide more info. ;)

Comment: Honestly I would like to provide more info, but I don't have it. Or better I'm not able to find it at the moment. Anyway Thanks for have tried to help me. I will probably close this question since there are too few info to get some help :(

Comment: Why can't you post the whole crash log instead of just this thread?